# doxygen QGDict Null key

Tags: doxygen

Using the latest 1.8.5 compiled from source and am getting hundreds of QGDict::hashAsciiKey errors:

```
Parsing file /home/build/CodeRepo/trunk/cvs/app/src/java/com/xiss/cvs/publisher/TopicCleanup.java...
Reading /home/build/CodeRepo/trunk/cvs/app/src/java/com/xiss/cvs/publQGDict::hashAsciiKey: Invalid null key
QGDict::hashAsciiKey: Invalid null key
QGDict::hashAsciiKey: Invalid null key
QGDict::hashAsciiKey: Invalid null key
```

Any ideas. I have not seen much on this lately (only some posts from 2005 ..)

Comment: Does the problem go away if you use the latest version from GitHub? If not please file a bug report in the bug tracker and attach a self contained example (source+config file in a zip) that allows me to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry. Been out for while. I just noticed the latest version released. So I'll try that first once I can succedssfully build it. See other post :-)

Comment: Latest version 1.8.6 does not have these errors anymore! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently I cannot put comment (requires 50 rep), so I have to answer.

I see this bug in 1.8.6.

I narrowed it down to having one headerfile named test.h containing this

```
union u
{
    struct
    {
      int a;
    };
};
```

And nothing else

I used a standard config generated by `doxygen -s -g`

Changed INPUT and FILE_PATTERN to match this one file.
The triggering part seems to be when I enabled dot `HAVE_DOT = YES`, and disabled hiding of undoc relations `HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS  = NO`

Rest of the options where left at default.

Hope this helps